# Version Create Error - Profile In Field - No CustomField named found

Tags: unlocked-package

I ran this command

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p MyPackage -d force-app -k test1234 --wait 20 -v DevHub
```

I get the errors below for the 2 profiles

```
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  Multiple errors occurred:
(1) Admin: In field: field - no CustomField named SomeManagedObject__c.SomeCustomFieldIAdded_A__c found
(2) CustomProfile2: In field: field - no CustomField named SomeManagedObject__c.SomeCustomFieldIAdded_A__c found
```

The strange thing is there is no error for `SomeManagedObject__c.SomeCustomFieldIAdded_B__c`

I did comparison for the `SomeCustomFieldIAdded_A__c` vs. `SomeCustomFieldIadded_B__c` and I can't seem to find why it errored for one and not the other.

Is the unlocked package mechanism Enterprise ready?  I was able to retrieve and deploy using Ant Deployment Tool.  However, switching over to 2GP unlock packaging process is a pain.  The same package.xml generates 29 strange errors that I got down to 20.

This package is dependent on 2 other managed packages.  I'm having trouble with just 1 out of 4 custom fields I added to 1 managed object.

Answer (score 0):

Admin profile = System Admin.
the In field/CustomField error went away after I did these.
Now, the original errors are gone but replaced with permission dependencies for the non-System Admin profile due to master/detail relationship.  But that's another issue

1. Add the name of the managed object to CustomObject section in the package.xml
2. add all the names of the custom fields I added to the managed object in the CustomField section in the package.xml

```
        <members>SomeManagedObject__c.SomeCustomFieldIAdded_A__c</members>
        <members>SomeManagedObject__c.SomeCustomFieldIAdded_B__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
   <types>
        <members>SomeManagedObject__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
```